# Divide rows into buckets given a group (bin) size in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Can you tell me as how to divide rows in bucket given a bin size in postgresql. I want to process every 100 row numbers (of lakhs of records) of a column.

Using ntile(value) we can distribute rows into (value) buckets used evenly.

For example,

| unit_no | ntile(2) | ntile(3) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4566 | 1 | 1 |
| 4322 | 1 | 1 |
| 6777 | 1 | 2 |
| 8755 | 2 | 2 |
| 9765 | 2 | 3 |
| 3235 | 2 | 3 |

But what I am looking for is to define size for every bin to group row records, without me having to define how many buckets in total is needed, as there are lakhs of records that's coming in and have to process every 100 records at a time.

So as to assign bucket as 1 for records 1-100 rows, bucket 2 for 101-200 rows and so on, just given a size of bin say 100 here.

The control argument is required on the size of bin (group size) rather than specified number of buckets in total.

Comment: Please try to avoid using words there are not globally understood, like *lakh*, and use more generic ones instead, like *million* or *thousand*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can calculate it by row_number, eg. for 100 items divide by 100 :

```
with temp_data as (
select * from generate_series(1,1000)
)
  
  select
  *,
  ((row_number() over() -1) / 100)::int +1 as bucket_nr
  from temp_data
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uBQ7stu6rvN9kdBSRLTFb6/0